# How to fill a column based on a condition using sum() for matches in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have struggles filling a column based on a condition. Maybe my approach is not in the right direction. I don't know. My conditions are as follow:

- 2 "b"s and 1 "a" in a row, write in column "match" "B"
- 2 "c"s in a row, write in column "match" "C"
- for anything else fill NA

So far I did the following but I see that this is not quite accurate since my new vector is not created from the rows but the entire column, and it still doesn't work.

```
set.seed(123)
df_letters <- data.frame(basket1 = sample(letters[1:3], 5,  replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.85,0.10,0.5)),
                        basket2 = sample(letters[1:3], 5,  replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.10,0.85,0.5)),
                        basket3 = sample(letters[1:3], 5,  replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.10,0.85)),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df_letters %>% mutate(match = ifelse(sum(as.character(as.vector(df_letters))  == "c")==2, "C", 
                                    ifelse((sum(as.character(as.vector(df_letters))  == "b")==2) & (sum(as.character(as.vector(df_letters))  == "a")==1) ,"B", NA  )))
```

My desired output is:

```
> df_letters
  basket1 basket2 basket3 match
1       a       b       b     B
2       c       b       c     C
3       a       c       a  <NA>
4       c       b       c     C
5       b       b       c  <NA>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df_letters %>%
 mutate(match = case_when(rowSums(select(., starts_with("basket")) == "b") == 2 & rowSums(select(., starts_with("basket")) == "a") == 1 ~ "B",
                          rowSums(select(., starts_with("basket")) == "c") == 2 ~ "C",
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_))

  basket1 basket2 basket3 match
1       a       b       b     B
2       c       b       c     C
3       a       c       a  <NA>
4       c       b       c     C
5       b       b       c  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to achieve this in `base R`:

```
df_letters$match <- apply(df_letters, 1, function(x) {
  count <- as.list(table(x))
  ifelse(count$a == 1 && count$b == 2, "B", ifelse(count$c == 2, "C", NA_character_))
})
```

The idea is to convert the `table` object to list to access counts by element.

**Output**

```
      basket1 basket2 basket3 match
1       a       b       b     B
2       c       b       c     C
3       a       c       a  <NA>
4       c       b       c     C
5       b       b       c  <NA>
```

Comment: I was playing with `apply()` as well because I knew it can go row-wise but I couldn't figure out how to set it correctly. Thank you very much!